# Function invoking only for first item React

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jsx, getelementbyid

i wrote code to expand "more info" block after clicking button, but function invoking only for first item.

Is it happening beacuse i use  `let more = document.getElementById("more");` ?

How can i change code for expanding only specifed item?

```
const Currency = ({ filteredItems, isLoading }) => {

    const addListeners = () => {
        let more = document.querySelectorAll(".more-info");
        more.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener("click", toggle)
        })
        console.log(more)
    }

    const toggle = () => {
       let more = document.getElementById("more");
        if (more.className === "more-info") {
            more.className = "more-info-active";
        } else {
            more.className = "more-info";
        }
    }

    return isLoading ? (<div className="loader">Loading...</div>) : (
        <div items={filteredItems}>
            {filteredItems.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id} className="item-wrapper">
                    <div className="item">
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <img src={item.image} alt="crypto symbol"></img>
                        <h3>{item.symbol}</h3>
                        <p>{item.current_price} pln</p>
                        <button onLoad={addListeners} onClick={toggle} className="info-btn" id="item-btn" >&#10140;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="more" className="more-info">
                        <div className="more-data">
                            <div className="info-text">
                                <p>high_24: {item.high_24h}</p>
                                <p>low_24: {item.low_24h}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>price_change_24h: {item.price_change_24h}</p>
                                <p>price_change_percentage_24h: {item.price_change_percentage_24h}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Sparklines className="sparkline" height={60} margin={10} data={item.sparkline_in_7d.price}>
                                    <SparklinesLine style={{fill:"none"}} color="#b777ff" />
                                </Sparklines>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Dont use document.getElement... , this is a Real DOM but React uses Virtual DOM.
2. Instead create a state with an array and on onClick event pass item as an argument and store in state , you can store only id e.g.
3. Last step, check in JSX if state includes item.id , if true then expand

this is an example , keep in mind this is not the only solution. Just simple example.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const fakeData = [
  {
    id: "123123-dfsdfsd",
    name: 'Title One',
    description: "Description bla bla bla One"
  },
  {
    id: "343434-dfsdfsd",
    name: 'Title Two',
    description: "Description bla bla bla Two"
  },
  {
    id: "6767676-dfsdfsd",
    name: 'Title Three',
    description: "Description bla bla bla Three"
  }
]

function App() {
  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([]);

  function _onToggle(item) {
    const isExist = tabs.includes(item.id)
    if (isExist) {
      setTabs(prevData => prevData.filter(pd => pd !== item.id))
    } else {
      setTabs(prevData => [item.id, ...prevData])
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      
      <div>
        {
          fakeData.map((item, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <h3 onClick={() => _onToggle(item)}>{item.name}</h3>
                <p style={{ display: tabs.includes(item.id) ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                  { item.description }
                </p>
              </div>
          ))
        }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```